# Tridion : Multimedia linking not working in the rich text box

Tags: tridion

I am trying to add the

```
<a href="tcm:45-6789">title</a>
```

in the rich text box. tcm:45-6789 is the id of pdf (multimedia component).

I have written razor to retrieve the content.
When I am publish the page it is creating the link as the component link of tridion not the mulimedia link.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. I tried explaining what happens when you add a Component Link to a rich-text field below. But if that doesn't help you, please update your question to make it clear what you are actually asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was resolved after adding the pdf(multimedia component) in Rich text box from Format tab and selecting type as component and browsing the multimedia component (pdf) instead of manually writing the a href="tcm:45-6789".
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how the Razor Mediator will handle this, but in a standard DWT TBB you would use:

```html
<a tridion:href="tcm:45-6789" tridion:type="Multimedia">title</a>
```

This would ensure the link is handled as the type Multimedia (using the Binary link resolver) rather than type Component which would use the standard Dynamic Component link resolver.

Optionally the Razor Mediator itself could be changed to identify the type of the Component which is used in the link and in case of a Multimedia Component, it could decide to use the Binary link to resolve it. But this would require a change to the Mediator code of course.

Comment: In an RTF this isn't handled properly in standard modular templating. I created a TBB that does what Bart suggests, plus a little extra iirc. You can find more infomation at https://forum.sdltridion.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=4853

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When you make component links in RTF it does not generate link to the binary. Check the  below sdl tridion world extension on exactly the same with solution.

https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/process-download-links.aspx